# Adding Data From Database to combobox

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a table that has one column named "Siniflar" in my database. I want to add all the data on that table to combobox. First i put the data to siniflarDataGridView and with "for .. next" i add them to combobox one by one. Is there easier way to add the data to combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the combox's DataSource DisplayMember and ValueMember properties appropriately.

If you showed us some of your code one could be more specific